# CPU Temp Advise

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I have a AMD X2 64 7750BE.

My system bios show my CPU temp is at 64 degrees centigrade(64C). **Is it too hot?**

MY CPU fan RPM is 2355. **Is the rpm speed normal?**

Answer (score 1):

According to a Google Search, a temperature between 40°C and 60°C is normal for this CPU, max is 75°C. But you could try to get a bigger heat sink.

Btw, You mean Celsius. ;)

Comment: Depends on what part of the world he's from  ... some countries use Centigrades, not Celsius in the name (same thing, different name).

Comment: @Idigas: Oh, didn't know that. Centigrad does sound to me like it is just a hundred of one celsius...well, in that case, sorry compu, I take that back!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a normal temperature for a processor. If your really worried you could look into getting a third party heatsink for it.

Answer (score 0):

Between 40* and 75* is fine. I've had my computer run up as much as 85* before.

Comment: I had a GeForce 8400GS, passive, which could run at 115 °C. And yes, it's still working (now active cooled ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on where do you live :-)

During summertime my CPU is much hotter.

So if you get 64C for air temperature around 20C, but you expect to have 40-45C during summertime, start looking for a better cooler.